# Сортировка строк тестового файла в случайном порядке

Tags: сортировка

Есть множество файлов .txt, где каждая строка - целое число. И строк таких в каждом по 3 миллиона и более.
**Задача** - отсортировать в случайном порядке.

1. есть ли готовые плагины для notepad++ под этого дело?
2. могу на php прочесть весь файл в массив, сделать shuffle и записать обратно. есть ли более быстрые варианты на php?
3. могу скопировать файл в excel, заполнить 2ю колонку случайными числами и сортировать по возрастанию по 2ой колонке. Это целесообразно или оч долго? А если файл на 10 млн строк?
4. какие вообще есть идеи по быстрой случайной сортировке?

Буду признателен за любые идеи.

Answer (score 1):

Все проблемы решило приложение KeyWordKeeper 5, рекомендую, 4млн строк за 5 секунд.

На php неправославно, тк файлы весят иногда по 50, а иногда по 100 мб, оч долго; в openoffice лимит на число строк :(